# Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: 'ms-allow-popups' is an invalid sandbox flag

Tags: excel, ms-office, sandbox, office-js

I want to make a very basic excel add-in. However I have got error after loading the xml file in `Excel Online`:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix these errors?

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>2145a915-4e7b-473f-a879-a5a5e8654152</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Microsoft</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Fun (online)"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Fun (online)"/>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="Workbook" />
  </Capabilities>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost/PRODSERVER/Fun/addin_online/Home.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

And `Home.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Fun (online)</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/Notification.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Home.js"></script>

    <link href="css/Common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/Office.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css">

  </head>
  <body class="ms-font-m">
    <div class="padding">
      <button class="ms-Button" id="open">open</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

So far as I know that first one is log noise from Microsoft (I see the same thing all the itme in Outlook), I haven't seen the second one but also looks unrelated to your add-in. Are you actually experiencing a problem?